# Wordpress plugin updates

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I am looking for some guidance with working with Wordpress. My company has recently decided to move to using Wordpress as our main development platform. I am used to doing OOP and I see that Wordpress has support for it which is great. I do have a few questions I was hoping some seasoned Wordpress developers could answer.

1.)We have designers that like to modify the layout of elements coming from a plugin. What is the best way to handle this from a plugin update standpoint so that there changes don't get overwritten in future updates? We will probably be making most of our own plugins and will be using the custom content types for them when available.

2.)From a client perspective what is the best way to handle urls for custom content (ex. Faqs plugin so that designers can handle layout and client can easily enter them). My initial thought was to create a cutom post type and make the slug through it. However, the drawback to this is that they cannot change the url from the pages section and add any custom content before the call to the plugin content. My second thought was to just use short codes but the downfall to that is client can accidentally remove it. Is there another way that I am missing or an even better way?

If anyone has any other tips/suggestions please feel free to leave them. Also any links to great articles/resources to working with Wordpress is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some general tips:

1. Always use the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/). Wordpress really has a good documentation.
2. Wordpress it's pretty procedural, but no one can stop you to use OOP. I really recommend you to make use of the autoloader. In your wp-config, you register the autoloader this way:

   define('LIB_PATH', realpath(dirname(**FILE**)) . '/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/lib');

   require LIB_PATH . '/MainFolder/Autoloader.php';

   spl_autoload_register('MainFolder_Autoloader::autoload');

Create a "lib" folder in your theme, and a "MainFolder" in the lib directory. Then in your MainFolder, you create the Autoloader.php file, which has this content:

```
class Autoloader
{
/**
 * Namespace.
 */
protected static $namespaces = array(
    'MainFolder'

);

/**
 * @param string $className
 * @return string|false
 */
public static function autoload($className)
{
    if (($classPath = self::getClassPath($className)) !== false) {
        return include $classPath;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

/**
 * @param string $className
 * @return string|false
 */
private static function getClassPath($className)
{
    $parts = explode("_", $className);

    foreach (self::$namespaces as $ns) {
        if (count($parts) && $parts[0] == $ns) {
            $path = LIB_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $parts) . '.php';
            if (is_readable($path)) {
                return $path;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Now in your "Mainfolder" you cand place all your classes, and access them in theme fille like this: for example, if you have an Upload.php you access it using Mainfolder_Upload. And you can place in your class all the public abstract functions you will need.

1. Make use of Custom post types. I recommend you [Custom post type Ui plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). It safes you from a lot of work.
2. Make use of [Page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates).
3. When you use ajax on your front, use admin-ajax.php file. More info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).
4. Use [wp enque script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) when you need to add some js scripts.
5. Learn about [hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).
6. Maybe your client needs some menus in the wp-admin. Learn [how to add administration menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus) in the wp-admin area.
7. When you're interfacing with the database use the global [$wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb).
8. I don't recommend to edit the foreign plugins files. On update, they cand delete your modifications.
9. Have fun :) Wordpress is really to use, and you cand find all the information on google :)

Comment: I voted you one up because you gave so much information most of which I am already aware of, but you didnt really answer my questions at all.

Comment: :)) thx, I know I didn't answer to your questions, but you said "If anyone has any other tips/suggestions please feel free to leave them" so I gladly offered you some tips on working with Wordpress :)